# Posix does not work in Flatpak package while it works in the ordinary compiled one

Tags: vala, flatpak

I have simple [vala](/questions/tagged/vala) app, one of its functionalities ends with shutting down the computer using `Posix.system("shutdown now");`
In the ordinary `ninja` compiled version, the app works fine. However, in the flatpak version, it does not work.
I tried to repackaging it again with adding couple of finish args in the yml file.,

```
finish-args:
  - '--share=ipc'
  - '--socket=fallback-x11'
  - '--socket=wayland'
  - '--filesystem=home'
  - '--socket=session-bus'
  - '--socket=system-bus'
```

but it does not work too.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely due to Flatpaks running in a sandbox with [limited permissions](https://docs.flatpak.org/en/latest/sandbox-permissions.html), this prevents access to other processes and limits access to the operating system.

You have given your Flatpak access to the system D-Bus, so you can try using the `PowerOff` method available through `org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager`.